# Как исправить ошибку AttributeError pyinstaller?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

компилирую программу с картинками на tkinter. Выходит такая ошибка:

```
24870 WARNING: Cannot read QLibraryInfo output: raised Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) when decoding:                                                                                                                      
False                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                                                                                   
  File "c:\users\fyodo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main                                                                                                                     
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,                                                                                                                                                                                       
  File "c:\users\fyodo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code                                                                                                                                
    exec(code, run_globals)                                                                                                                                                                                                          
  File "C:\Users\fyodo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>                                                                                                           
  File "c:\users\fyodo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 114, in run                                                                                                        
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))                                                                                                                                                                                   
  File "c:\users\fyodo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 65, in run_build                                                                                                   
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)                                                                                                                                                            
  File "c:\users\fyodo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 720, in main                                                                                            
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))                                                                                                                                                   
  File "c:\users\fyodo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 667, in build                                                                                           
    exec(code, spec_namespace)                                                                                                                                                                                                       
  File "D:\projects\SuperCrypto\Code\GUI\sp.spec", line 6, in <module>                                                                                                                                                               
    a = Analysis(['sp.py'],                                                                                                                                                                                                          
  File "c:\users\fyodo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 242, in __init__                                                                                        
    self.__postinit__()                                                                                                                                                                                                              
  File "c:\users\fyodo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 160, in __postinit__                                                                                    
    self.assemble()                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
  File "c:\users\fyodo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 419, in assemble                                                                                        
    self.graph.process_post_graph_hooks()                                                                                                                                                                                            
  File "c:\users\fyodo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\s
    File "c:\users\fyodo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\imphook.py", line 440, in post_graph                                                                                           
    self._load_hook_module()                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  File "c:\users\fyodo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\imphook.py", line 406, in _load_hook_module                                                                                    
    self._hook_module = importlib_load_source(                                                                                                                                                                                       
  File "c:\users\fyodo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\compat.py", line 588, in importlib_load_source                                                                                        
    return mod_loader.load_module()                                                                                                                                                                                                  
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 462, in _check_name_wrapper                                                                                                                                                    
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 962, in load_module                                                                                                                                                            
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 787, in load_module                                                                                                                                                            
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 265, in _load_module_shim                                                                                                                                                               
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 702, in _load                                                                                                                                                                           
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked                                                                                                                                                                  
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module                                                                                                                                                            
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed                                                                                                                                                       
  File "c:\users\fyodo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\hook-PySide2.py", line 26, in <module>                                                                                          
    collect_system_data_files(pyside2_library_info.location['PrefixPath'],                                                                                                                                                           
  File "c:\users\fyodo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\hooks\qt.py", line 89, in __getattr__                                                                                           
    return getattr(self, name)                                                                                                                                                                                                       
  File "c:\users\fyodo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\hooks\qt.py", line 91, in __getattr__                                                                                           
    raise AttributeError                                                                                                                                                                                                             
AttributeError
```

Как можно решить?
Заранее спасибо

Comment: Покажите Ваш код

Comment: он огромный,около 3000 строок

Comment: Хотя бы ту часть, где ошибка